# Open a Colorbox within a div block instead of whole page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I am currently building a Jquery interactive game and I'm using the jQuery Colorbox plugin to show messages to user.

The thing is, all the game is inside a div and I need that Colorbox to open inside that div (that container div is `overflow:hidden`).

I want Colorbox to work the same way it does by default, centered, but in a div block instead of the whole body.

I tried to change this line in colorbox.js:

```
$(document.body).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
```

Into this:

```
$("#game").append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
```

But it isn't working. Do you have any idea?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A little late on this answer...

Im looking at line 300 of jquery.colorbox.js.

Change: 
$window = $(window);

TO:

$window = $(".Class");